# Using the squeeze theorem to prove continuity at a point

Tags: real-analysis

I have used the squeeze theorem plenty of times to prove a limit of a function however now i've been asked to prove the continuity of a function at a certain point. Please could somebody give me some ideas as how to go about this?

it's the function $$f(x)= \begin{cases} xsin(1/x) & \text{ if $x \ne 0$}\\
                                 0  & \text{if  $x=0$}\end{cases}$$
 and i need to prove the continuity at 0 using the squeeze theorem

Comment: A function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ exactly when $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)$ (i) exists and (ii) equals $f(0)$. Sounds like you know how to do (i); (ii) is easier.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $ 0\leq |x\sin \frac{1}{x}| \leq |x|$,so from the squeeze theorem you get $\lim_{x\to0} |x\sin \frac{1}{x}| =0 $.